# DictionaryEntry and KeyValuePair

Tags: .net, collections, dictionary, key-value

when KeyValuePair and DictionaryEntry are used?

Please help me in detail. I really need to know.

Comment: If you really need to know then you would know when and where too. And should we assume .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DictionaryEntry` is used for the old .NET 1.0 non generic `Hashtable` class. The generic `Dictionary` class, introduced in .NET 2.0, uses `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: KeyValuePair can only used with Dictionary class.